# Wordpress: Cannot load module 'XCache'

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel, error-log

I get this warning in my website error log:

`PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'XCache' because conflicting module 'eAccelerator' is already loaded in Unknown on line 0`

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have to remove either `XCache` or `eAccelerator` from your php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

I am also receiving this problem in the error log file.

Apparently, eAccelerator or XCache are Apache caching modules which are meant to speed your site.

At a time, you can have Xcache enabled or eAccelerator. since both are powerful caching module, enabling both at a time will surely create a conflict.

To solve this problem:
Edit the php.ini file under /usr/local/lib/php.ini in your web server..

Search for the line: extension=xcache.so

Remove this line and save..